# Why does the program work well with the double type and not with float type?

Tags: class, haskell, types, double

Hi i am a newbie with the haskell programming, i wrote this piece of code:

```
f :: a->Bool
f x = True

g :: a->Bool 
g x = False

class P a where
   func :: a->Bool

instance P Integer where
   func x = f x

instance P Float where
   func x = g x
```

if i call the function `func` as `func 23.3` Ghci returns the follow error:

`<interactive>:6:6:
    Ambiguous type variable a0' in the constraints:
      (Fractional a0)
        arising from the literal 23.3' at <interactive>:6:6-9
      (P a0) arising from a use of func' at <interactive>:6:1-4
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the first argument of func', namely 23.3'
    In the expression: func 23.3
    In an equation for it': it = func 23.3`

while the code works fine if i call `func` with an Integer as parameter. If i replace the `Float` instance of P with a `Double` instance the code works correctly with the call `func 23.3`. Why?

Comment: Note that [there's no real reason to ever use `Float` in Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Floating_point), so in fact you should replace the instance with `Double` regardless of this monomorphism-restriction hassle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the infamous Monomorphism restriction.  GHCi doesn't know what type to turn `23.3` into specifically, and there are multiple `Fractional a` data types (notably `Double` and `Float`).

You can disable this with

```
> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
```

Or better yet

```
> func (23.3 :: Float)
```

---

The reason for this is because the literal `23.3` has type

```
> :type 23.3
23.3 :: Fractional a => a
```

Instead of a more concrete type like `Float` or `Int`.  This actually allows you to implement your own types which can be represented by number literals (a handy trick at times).  Unfortunately, it gives a rather unhelpful error message that confuses most every beginner.  The compiler has to have a specific type, though, because you could have also added

```
instance P Double where
    func x = undefined
```

And then it would have to decide which instance of `func` to use for a literal like `23.3`.  The best practice is to just specify which type you are using inline like I showed above.

Probably the reason why it worked in GHCi with `Double` is because GHCi will sometimes attempt to coerce types into something more concrete for convenience.  This is why if you were to do

```
> let x = [1..]
> :type x
x :: [Integer]
```

When instead `x` should have type `(Enum a, Num a) => [a]`.  When you have the Monomorphism restriction enabled (by default), GHCi will try to make the types work with `Integer`, `Double`, `IO`, as opposed to `Integral a => a`, `Double a => a` or `Monad m => m`.  It just doesn't work well in every case.

Comment: Without intending to un-fustigate the monomorphism restriction: I think this is one of the rare cases where it's actually useful, because indeed it almost never makes sense to use `Float`.